# cannot change font awesome icon after click

Tags: html, jquery

I have a jquery Script in my master page

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    alert(this.id);
    $('#' + this.id).removeClass("fa fa-cog").addClass("fas fa-spinner fa-spin");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-2">
  <button type="button" id="btnGenerateReport" class="btn btn-default btnGenerateReport" aria-label="Left Align" runat="server">
            <span class="fa fa-cog" runat="server" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
</div>
```

I am trying to change the span class to the spinner. On clicking, the fa-spinner class is added along with fa-cog, and button itself is spinning which is not what I want. I just want the fa-cog icon to change to the fa-spinner icon.

Comment: Then don't add `fa-spin`?

Comment: @freedomn-m that stopped the button from spinning . but now i see bot cog and spinner (which is not spinning ) on the button. How do i hide that cog and make the spinner run ?

Comment: You're adding the classes to the button, not the span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the element id. You changes the button class not the span.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    alert(this.id);
    $('#' + this.id).children('span').removeClass("fa fa-cog").addClass("fas fa-spinner fa-spin");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-2">
  <button type="button" id="btnGenerateReport" class="btn btn-default btnGenerateReport" aria-label="Left Align" runat="server">
            <span class="fa fa-cog" runat="server" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the classes on the button, not the span. Target the span with `.find()`

```js
  $("button").click(function () {
    $(this).find('span').removeClass("fa-cog").addClass("fa-spinner fa-spin");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-2">
  <button type="button" id="btnGenerateReport" class="btn btn-default btnGenerateReport" aria-label="Left Align" runat="server">
            <span class="fa fa-cog" runat="server" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
</div>
```